# Why use three routers for security purposes instead of two?

Tags: network, router, isolation

I bought a new router to isolate devices in my network, but then I found that famous Steve Gibdson's Three Dumb Routers episode. I have read the whole transcript but even so I didn't get why only two routers is not enough to isolate my local network.

Three Dumb Routers suggests this:

```
        No trusted devices       
                |
             Router 3  
                |           
Internet --- Router 1 --- Router 2
                             |
                      Trusted devices
```

But I was thinking in trying this:

```
        No trusted devices       
                |             
Internet --- Router 1 --- Router 2
                             |
                      Trusted devices
```

with router 2 being connected to router 1 by WAN port. Is this/why is this not enough?

Comment: The way it looks right now (unless we get more details), it looks like your trusted devices can route out to the untrusted devices. Ideally you'd have both of those routers connected to the LAN ports of another router, so that you can't go from trusted -> untrusted. This is assuming these devices are all behind NAT.

Comment: [Don't listen to Gibson](https://www.theregister.com/2002/02/25/steve_gibson_invents_broken_syncookies/). Rather, stay with a router operating system that is up to date (e.g. pfsense, opnsense, lede, your favorite linux distro etc), and ensure that management interface is only availble on truster interfaces. Consumer routers often have age old firmware with gaping security problems. It also confuses NAT and firewall; NAT is ***not*** a security mechanism.

Comment: @vidarlo But does my plan with just two routers achieves isolation between those devices? I don't want to untrusted devices to being possible to connect to trusted devices.

Comment: It depends on how they're configured. You can't rely on NAT for that; you need a firewall. And if the router is running a Linux kernel from 2012 with gaping vulnerabilities, you risk the *very device* you want to protect you to [become an attack vector](https://routersecurity.org/consumerrouters.php). In addition, it's harder to manage than one device.

Comment: Why not just set up one router with VLANs? Much less to manage.

Comment: @multithr3at3d My router doesn't support it :/

Comment: @Mycroft Then get a proper router that supports this. As your router is probably run-of-the-mill SOHO shit, it probably runs a ten year old Linux kernel with a ton of known vulnerabilities as well. Getting three shitty routers won't improve security in any significant way.